# Hibernate criteria.setFetchSize is not working

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, autocomplete, criteria

I am working on performance improvement. We are using Hibernate Criteria retrieve data from database(Oracle). In our application we are using autocomplete for input field retrieving a lot of data. The problem occurs where we are typing `%%%`(retrieving everything from table, over 30000 records) and there is just to much data, and browser is going to slow or freez.
I tried `criteria.setFetchSize()` for load only specyfic number of records and load some more when we reached the max but for some reason it's not working as expected(still getting the whole table). The `criteria.setMaxResult()` works fine but there is no point to use it.
Do you guys have any idea how to improve this one?

There is the method:

```
  public List<Device> getDeviceInOrderSerial(final Integer offset, final Integer limit, final String orderNo) {

    final Criteria criteria = this.createCriteria();
    if (StringUtils.hasLength(orderNo)) {

      criteria.createAlias("this.orders", "ord");
      criteria.createAlias("this.article", "ar");
      final Criterion serialRestr = Restrictions.ilike("ord.no", orderNo);
      criteria.add(serialRestr);

      final ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
      projList.add(Property.forName("ord.no"), "no");
      projList.add(Property.forName("ar.name"), "name");

      criteria.setFirstResult(offset);
      criteria.setProjection(projList);
      criteria.addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.asc("ord.no"));
      criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
      criteria.setFetchSize(limit);
    }

    return this.criteriaResult(criteria);
  }
```

Comment: [Criteria#setFetchSize](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFetchSize(int)) calls [Statement#setFetchSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html?is-external=true#setFetchSize(int)) method under the hood. This is only a hint to the database driver how many rows should be fetched with each database round trip. This does not limit the number of records in any way, use `Criteria#setMaxResult` instead. Why can't you use this method, please explain ?

Comment: Well i've used it but lets say i set this on 100 and it fine because i get only 100 records but where is the rest. I want load automatically another 100 after i reach the bottom of list and so on. 
Well perhaps there is any misunderstanding from my site or lack of knowledge about this.

Comment: Then use `setMaxResults` together with [Criteria#setFirstResult](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFirstResult(int)). Say use a constant `setMaxResults(100)` and `setFirstResult(0)` for the first batch of records, `setFirstResult(100)` for the second batch, `200` for 3rd and so on. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination) to learn how to implement the pagination in Hibernate.